# How to customize the ckeditor from cakecoded?

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, ckeditor

Morning,
I downloaded ckeditor with the cakecoded plugin as shown in the github page https://github.com/CakeCoded/CkEditor, but I don't know where to customize it since I don't see a folder named ckeditor inside my application.

From my mac terminal I did this: composer require cakecoded/cakephp. When I call the ckeditor in my view like this:  `<?= echo $this->Ck->input('Media_content'); ?>`,the ckeditor does appear but the image and flash icons are not working properly. So I decided to customize the ckeditor in adding image plugin or ckfinder, but the problem is that I did not get a ckeditor folder after the download was completed, so I don't know where to customize the ckeditor from.
I've tried to manually download ckeditor, first in the webroot/js folder and then in the plugins folder, but none of these manually downloaded ckeditors are being used by my views, and so all the configurations I make are not changing the ckeditor's behavior.

I'm having this in my composer.json:

"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\": "src/",
            "CkEditor\": "./plugins/CkEditor/src/"
        }
    },

{
"name": "cakephp/app",
    "description": "CakePHP skeleton app",
    "homepage": "https://cakephp.org",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "cakecoded/ckeditor": "^1.0",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "3.7.*",
        "cakephp/migrations": "^2.0.0",
        "cakephp/plugin-installer": "^1.0",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "2.*"

I'm racking my brain trying to figure out this puzzle for 2 days but without any success. Any help would be appreciated.